# Concatenate Collections with Java 8

Tags: java, guava, java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate over a collection of collections. With Guava I would do this:

```
import static com.google.collections.Iterables.*;

class Group {
    private Collection<Person> persons;
    public Collection<Person> getPersons();
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    public String getName();
}

Collection<Group> groups = ...;
Iterable<Person> persons = concat(transform(groups, Group::getPersons()));
Iterable<String> names = transform(persons, Person::getName);
```

But how can I do the same thing with Java 8 streams?

```
groups.stream().map(Group::getPersons())...?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with flat mapping all elements of a stream into your stream.

Let me explain by this code:

```
groups.stream()
        .flatMap(group -> group.getPersons().stream());
```

What you do here, is:

1. Obtain a `Stream<Collection<Group>>`.
2. Then flat map every obtained `Stream<Person>`, from a `Group`, back into your original stream, which is of type `Stream<Person>`.

Now after the `flatMap()`, you can do whatever you want with the obtained `Stream<Person>`.

Comment: Will this evaluation still be lazy? If I want, for instance, only to find out the first name of the first person?

Comment: @PhilippJardas Yes, *most* `Stream<E>` operations are lazy. You can find more about which ones are not lazy in the javadoc, for example `sorted()` is not lazy.

Comment: Great, thanks! Although there are several correct answers, I will accept this one because it was the first. :-)

Comment: @PhilippJardas JBNizet and RohitJain were actually faster.

Answer (score 6):

```
Stream<Person> persons = groups.stream().flatMap(g -> g.getPersons().stream());
```

Comment: Hmmyep, not very "elegant" ;) I guess someone somewhere is already coming up with a `Streams.concat()`... Although they'd have to be careful with these stream's `.characteristics()`

Comment: How is it not elegant? It's a classical functional idiom, and it's completely lazy. Why would Streams.concat() be more elegant?

Comment: +1 If you tried to implement `concat`, you'd find yourself ending up with `flatMap(x->x)`. In Clojure I actually couldn't decide whether to `(apply concat ...)` or `(flatmap identity ...)`.

Comment: @JBNizet it would be more elegant if they allowed me to pass a function returning Collection instead, since 9 times out of 10 that's what I have available on the methods on the object.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need `flatMap`:

```
Stream<Person> persons = groups.stream().flatMap(g -> g.getPersons().stream());
```